# Cross product of a vector with local y direction and another vector

Tags: c++, vector, glm-math, cross-product

So I have a cube represented by a `glm::mat4  m_yellow_mat`

[image]

and I performed a `30 degree` rotation around `z-axis`

```
m_yellow_mat = glm::rotate(m_yellow_mat, glm::radians(30), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
```

Now refer the below picture

[image]

I want to find the cross product between the blue vector and red vector

I know the blue vector, but not sure how to find the red vector? Red vector represents the direction of the local y axis of cube?

```
cross( ?????? , blue_vector);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local y axis in world space is stored in the second row of the matrix:

```
vec3 yaxis_world = normalize(m_yellow_mat[1][0], m_yellow_mat[1][1], m_yellow_mat[1][2]);
```

Explanation:

The y axis in object space (let's call it yaxis) is by definition [0,1,0]. In order to transform a vector from object space to world space, we multiply the vector with the model matrix. Since we are interested in a direction, the homogeneous coordinate has to be 0:

```
axisy_world = modelMatrix * yaxis

axisy_world = modelMatrix * [0,1,0,0]
```

When looking at the matrix multiplication, we notice that the this will return exactly the second row of the matrix.

Note, that the result has to be normalized in order to cancel out scaling factors from the matrix. If it is guaranteed that only translations/rotations are contained, the normalization can be skipped.

Comment: then local x axis would be `m_yellow_mat[0][0], m_yellow_mat[0][1], m_yellow_mat[0][2]` ?

Comment: @MrRobot9: Yes. Basically, each row of a transformation matrix stores the principle axis of the local space.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from BDL already nailed down the point that you can get such *up vector* representing local coordinate of your object as seen in the scene from its 2nd column transformation matrix.

---

I'd like to go further as it might be benefit for other readers for another perspective of why we can extract such vectors out of transformation matrix itself.

First of all, we can extract the following directional vectors from transformation matrix (resultant matrix from your matrix operation i.e. translation, rotation, scaling)

- its 1st column represents **left vector** of the object
- its 2nd column represents **up vector** of the object
- its 3rd column represents **forward vector** of the object

This is somewhat related to how *view matrix* is constructed. It will help answering of why those information lie in there.

For immediate usage, if we have 4x4 matrix, we can just ignore the last column which is positional components, and if you know such matrix is scaled or just want to make sure then normalize it before making use of extracted column vector from matrix.

### Constructing view matrix

From constructing *view matrix* we know that it's just **reverse** from what we will normally do to a certain object in the world. As there is no such thing as camera in OpenGL or possibly any rendering API out there, it's just a virtual thing.

To achieve the effect of camera, and able to simulate player movement or look into specific direction, we do exactly the opposite (use right-handed rule here as used by OpenGL in world space, and by default in GLM)

1. to have camera moved by dx,dy,dz => `0,0,10` : what we do is translating all the objects in the scene by `0,0,-10`.
2. for rotation, it's a little bit tricky, but simply it's inverse of rotational matrix.

By multiplying the twos above together we will get

```
view_matrix = inverse(M_rotation) * M_translation
```

you can [read more](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_camera.html) about this as it's well written by *Song Ho*.

Notable excerpt from his article, we would get

[image]

Notice *Left*, *up*, and *forward* vectors are in there. In summary, view matrix is like manipulating or simulating the world to satisfy the camera interaction, it's still interacting with world space in a sense.

### Now what?

As we saw view matrix construction, it's similar concept applied. We can use it with an object in the scene itself with 3 differences

1. *forward vector* is now pointing from the object itself to the target (opposite from view matrix construction) as now it's the object that will be rotated not other objects.
2. we don't need positional matrix (per se positional information), we only care about the direction (thus this eliminate the needs to adjust positional components as we don't need negative in front of positional components)
3. we don't need to apply inverse matrix to rotational matrix as we are not operating on a camera, but the object itself
4. 2. and 3. combined we can deduce into a 3x3 rotational matrix, or 4x4 matrix with `0,0,0,1` at the last column.

In short, `m_yellow_mat` you get packs up with *left*, *up*, and *forward* vectors representing the object local axis. You can directly extract it out as follows

- `glm::vec3 left = glm::vec3(m_yellow_mat[0]);`
- `glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(m_yellow_mat[1]);`
- `glm::vec3 forward = glm::vec3(m_yellow_mat[2]);`

### (Extra) A little further: One vector can represent orientation of object

Further benefit of knowing how *view matrix* is constructed. A single directional vector can represent the object's orientation without us to maintain 3 matrix rotation per axis, but it comes with a lost of one single information (which is mostly rolling around z-axis) **only if** we don't have *up vector* at hand at that moment; but mostly it's not that important for a simple object like gizmo, plane or per se something that you just want it to orient into a right direction provided you know its initial starting orientation which must be facing into +z-axis, up at y-axis.

The code to do this which is simpler form of how view matrix is constructed as I learned this from Song Ho's implementation with slightly modification to suit my example.

```
glm::mat4 computeLookAtForObject(const glm::vec3& pos, const glm::vec3& target)
{
    glm::vec3 forward = glm::normalize(target - pos);
    glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // handle if forward is nearly the same as up vector
    // then we choose another direction for forward
    if (std::abs(forward.x) < kEpsilon && std::abs(forward.z) < kEpsilon)
    {
        if (forward.y > 0.0f)
        {
            up.x = 0.0f;
            up.y = 0.0f;
            up.z = -1.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            up.x = 0.0f;
            up.y = 0.0f;
            up.z = 1.0f;
        }
    }

    glm::vec3 left = glm::normalize(glm::cross(up, forward));
    up = glm::cross(forward, left);

    glm::mat4 m = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    m[0] = glm::vec4(left, 0.0f);
    m[1] = glm::vec4(up, 0.0f);
    m[2] = glm::vec4(forward, 0.0f);
    //m[3] = glm::vec4(pos, 1.0f);  // <--- (optional) we can completely ignore this, or build up full-feature matrix from this function as well by uncommenting this line
    return m;
}
```

such function is used in my example as well.

### Also yet another perspective

To support the idea of local coordinate extraction right from the matrix.

I quoted the following from *F.Dunn 3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game development* book at *section 7.2.1* (note: the book use row-major column)

> If we interpret the rows of a matrix as the basis vectors of a coordinate space, then multiplication by the matrix performs a coordinate space transformation. If `aM=b`, we say that `M` tranformed `a` to `b`.

So it is for columns of a matrix in our case.

Another quotes from the same section,

> The bottom line is that there's nothing especially magical about matrices. They simply provide a compact way to represent the mathematical operations required to perform a coordinate space transformation.

### Examples

I've created two examples to validate this.

1. Use matrix operations to get resultant matrix, then extract its 3 directional vectors to draw it on screen. This uses plane as geometry. Check at [haxpor/lgl - 1](https://github.com/haxpor/lgl/tree/master/src/DecomposeDirVectorsFromWorldMatrix2)

[image]

2. Use a single lookAt vector to orient a plane without maintaining multiple matrices. Make use of `computeLookAtForObject()` above. Check at [haxpor/lgl - 2](https://github.com/haxpor/lgl/tree/master/src/DecomposeDirVectorsFromWorldMatrix)

[image]

Both of example, can be simply hit `make` after go right into such directory. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, Linux.

### Credits

- Thanks to [Song Ho](http://www.songho.ca/) for informative writeup for these subjects.